# How can I export my current VSCode configuration and import in an out of the box VSCode installation on another computer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, workflow

I just finished to establish a personal workflow in visual studio code, at home (all of it because remote work because of COVID situation) and in a couple of weeks we are going to return to the office, so, I wanted to know, how can I export all my keybindings config, terminal config etc and import it on my work visual studio code installation?

regards,

Charlie.

Comment: Look into `Settings Sync` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync - you need to be using the Insiders' Build though.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself in a similar situation to the OP.

Here is a **partial solution** that worked for me.

See this [reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/93280j/how_can_i_export_snippets/e3a7tlw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

I copied my vscode snippets

**from**: windows 10 >> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets

**to**: Windows 11 Home Insider Edition Version 21H2 >>
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets

It worked great.